# Is it possible to parameterise the NUnit test case display name when using ``Ticked method names``?

Tags: f#, nunit

I am testing out F# and using NUnit as my test library; I have discovered the use of double-back ticks to allow arbitrary method naming to make my method names even more human readable.

I was wondering, whether rightly or wrongly, if it is possible to parameterise the method names when using NUnit's `TestCaseAttribute` to change the method name, for example:

```
[<TestCase("1", 1)>]
[<TestCase("2", 2)>]
let ``Should return #expected when "#input" is supplied`` input expected =
    ...
```

Comment: I wouldnt be surprised if the Test Case Name rendering in NUnit was customizable if you had a different `TestCaseAttribute` but no, its not an intrinsically supported feature and is not likely to become one given that few other .NET languages support such arbitrary naming. Also I think while it works great for this case, it's not a generally useful enough concept to consider supporting as a core thing.

Comment: Fuchu can trivially do this: https://github.com/mausch/Fuchu/blob/master/Fuchu.Tests/Tests.fs#L306-L312

Comment: I have been looking at the TickSpec (http://tickspec.codeplex.com/) video which is almost what I am after, thought I would share with the guys here that do not know about TickSpec already: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UuTL3nj9fIE#t=12

Comment: @MauricioScheffer ahh missed your link, looks cool I will definitely check it out thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might not be exactly what you need, but if you want to go beyond unit testing, then [TickSpec](http://tickspec.codeplex.com/) (a BDD framework using F#) has a nice feature where it lets you write parameterized scenarios based on back-tick methods that contain regular expressions as place holders.

For example, in [Phil Trelford's blog post](http://trelford.com/blog/post/Examples.aspx), he uses this to define tic-tac-toe scenario:

```
Scenario: Winning positions
    Given a board layout:
        | 1 | 2 | 3 |
        | O | O | X |
        | O |   |   |
        | X |   | X |
    When a player marks X at <row> <col>
    Then X wins

Examples:
    | row    | col    | 
    | middle | right  |
    | middle | middle |
    | bottom | middle |
```

The method that implements the `When` clause of the scenario is defined in F# using something like this:

```
let [<When>] ``a player marks (X|O) at (top|middle|bottom) (left|middle|right)`` 
        (mark:string,row:Row,col:Col) =       
    let y = int row             
    let x = int col        
    Debug.Assert(System.String.IsNullOrEmpty(layout.[y].[x]))
    layout.[y].[x] <- mark
```

This is a neat thing, but it might be an overkill if you just want to write a simple parameterized unit test - BDD is useful if you want to produce human readable specifications of different scenarios (and there are actually other people reading them!)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, TickSpec will do what I am after (not exactly, but well enough) and I have added a link to the video as a comment on my question.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

The basic issue is that for every `input` and `expected` you need to create a unique function.  You would then need to pick the correct function to call (or your stacktrace wouldn't make sense).  As a result this is not possible.

Having said that if you hacked around with something like `eval` (which must exist inside fsi), it might be possible to create something like this, but it would be very slow.

Comment: Think the OP means could NUnit (/xUnit) generate a Test Case DisplayName with the tokens replaced. i.e. `Should return 1 when "1" is supplied` etc. instead of `ShouldReturnTransformedFromOriginal(1, "1")`

Comment: @RubenBartelink yes, that's exactly what I was asking after.